# How to speed up a "append to file" kind of program?

Tags: python, file

I was creating search algorithm and for that I needed data in huge amounts so I decided to create a file which will contain random words taken from the `english-words` module. For that I created this small code to be run from CMD:

```py
def create_very_large_file(filename='very_large_file.txt'):
    from english_words import english_words_set as ews
    import random

    _ews = list(ews)
    print('Creating a very large file...')
    with open(filename, 'w') as large_file:
        large_file.close()

    with open(filename, 'a') as large_file:
        for i in range(1000000000):
            print(f'Work Done: {round((i/1000000000)*100, 8)}\t|{"▐" * int((i/1000000000)*100)}{" " * int(100 - ((i/1000000000)*100))}|', end='\r')
            if i % 10 == 0:
                large_file.write('\n')
            word = random.choice(_ews)
            large_file.write(word + ' ')
        large_file.close()
    print('A very large file created !!')
```

Now the speed of this code is around 3,600,000 words per minute, appended to the file, which will take more than an hour to create a file this big.

And since I have a Ryzen 9, this process would be much slower in other PCs.

Is there any way this kind of work can be done faster ?

Comment: Do you really have the `print` in the inner loop? Console output takes a relatively long time and is likely slowing things down **a lot**. Beyond that, consider creating the file in memory as much as possible and write it out periodically in large chunks if it's too big to fit all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of work each iteration does (and reduce the number of iterations by a factor of 10) by building a complete line in each iteration.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as large_file:
    for i in range(100_000_000):
        words = random.choices(_ews, k=10)
        print(' '.join(words), file=large_file)
```

---

For the number of iterations you still have remaining, there's no reason to try to update your progress bar on *every* iteration. One update per 10,000 or even 100,000 iterations would probably be sufficient.

---

You are also doing several times more work than necessary for each progress bar update. Compute `(i/1000000000)*100` *once*.

```
if i % 10_000 == 0:
    x = i / 1_000_000
    total = round(x, 8)
    done = int(x)
    remaining = int(100 - x)
    print(f'Work Done: {total}\t|{"▐" * done}{" " * remaining}|', end='\r')
```

Comment: okay this one really helped. by the time 13% was done with this, only 2% was done in my original method